# Angular Data Binding in TS class

Tags: angular, typescript

In my component, I specify a property that is bound on the UI.

**Component**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    public propertyA:string;
    public propertyB:string;

}
```

**UI**

```
<textarea matInput rows="10" 
placeholder="Body" [(ngModel)]="formData.propertyA" 
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></textarea>
```

How do I do something like:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    public propertyA:string = "Some text with {{propertyB}} bound.";
    public propertyB:string;

}
```

So basically, I bind propertyA to the textbox and nested within propertyA is the value of propertyB, which updates according to another databinding?

Comment: ``public get propertyA() { return `Some text with ${this.propertyB} bound.`}``

Comment: Your HTML and TS code are incompatible with each other. But, I've made some assumptions and written an answer. Feel free to edit your question to be correct. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

public propertyA:string = `Some text with ${this.propertyB} bound.`;
public propertyB:string;
```

}

You can try with this  [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

If we need to keep  `propertyA` in-sync with `propertyB` and not just initially compute it:

**I Getters**

The easiest way to do that is `getters`. Keep in mind that using `getter/functions` in template will execute it on every Change Detection cycle (keep this executable as simple as possible).

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    public get propertyA():string {
        `Some text with ${this.propertyB} bound.`;
    };
    public propertyB:string;

}
```

**II Observable**

Better way is to use Observable for a value that can be changed over time.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    public propertyA = this.propertyB.pipe(
        map(propertyB => `Some text with ${propertyB} bound.`),
    );
    // BehaviorSubject is Subject that have initial value and repeat the last value
    public propertyB: Observable<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');

    // somewhere
    foo(){
        this.propertyB.next('New value');
    }
}

// template
<div>propertyA: {{propertyA | async}}</div>
<div>propertyB: {{propertyB | async}}</div>
```

Comment: What makes the `Observable` better? I'd say it's merely more complex ;-).

Comment: `getter` will be executed on every CD cycle (it is easy to make mistake and place there some heavy computations), Observable is more composable and it is `angularish way` )

Comment: "Observable is more composable and it is angularish way" isn't a statement specific to this case. It's best to not choose the solution merely because it potentially has the most benefits, because in this particular case it's just way more complicated.

Comment: You are right but my first statement was that with getter is easy to make mistake.